# Finding a specific letters and any number in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and I want to find a string that contains a specific combination of letters follow by unknown numbers ('rs#').

My data frame

```
 df = pd.DataFrame ({
        'First Column Name':  ['cetrem', 'BBB'],
        'Second Column Name': ['CCC', 'rscat'],
        'Third Column Name' : ['rs001', 'def']
    })
```

And some code I have been using

```
rs = df[df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains("rs"))].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

With this code I obtain **rs001** but also **rscat** and I do not wish this.

Would there be any modification that I could add to the code already written above to select rs# instead of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rs = df[df.apply(lambda x:x.str.contains("rs\d+"))].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

This will only capture `rs#anyamountofdigits`

Comment: @ManuelDominguez u can refine more to make it only capture `rs` grouped